# A question regarding the implementation of std::add_pointer

Tags: c++, std

From [std::add_pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_pointer)

> Possible implementation

```
namespace detail {

template <class T>
struct type_identity { using type = T; }; // or use std::type_identity (since C++20)

template <class T>
auto try_add_pointer(int) -> type_identity<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type*>;
template <class T>
auto try_add_pointer(...) -> type_identity<T>;

} // namespace detail

template <class T>
struct add_pointer : decltype(detail::try_add_pointer<T>(0)) {};
```

The description for the above (possible) implementation reads:

> If T is a reference type, then provides the member typedef type which
>   is a pointer to the referred type.
>
> Otherwise, if T names an object type, a function type that is not cv-
>   or ref-qualified, or a (possibly cv-qualified) void type, provides the
>   member typedef type which is the type T*.
>
> Otherwise (if T is a cv- or ref-qualified function type), provides the
>   member typedef type which is the type T.

In the (possible) implementation code above, apparently `struct add_pointer` derives from the type returned by `detail::try_add_pointer<T>(0)`.

What is the logic behind deriving from the type returned by the overload of `detail::try_add_pointer<T>` taking `int` argument, to resolve the member `typedef type` to one of the three possibilities described above? Specifically, how does this address the possibility if `T` is a `cv-` or `ref-`qualified function type?

Comment: The description for the above (possible) implementation reads:

`If T is a reference type, then provides the member typedef type which is a pointer to the referred type.`

Then delete this comment right now. GN DD Whats the question? and what are we addressing

`What is the logic behind deriving from the type returned by the overload of `

I am not even sure that really makes any sense...

Comment: Instead of `struct add_pointer : ` it can be `using add_pointer = `.

Comment: O rite So that means the grammer is different rigth Symbols Numbers What is that comment.

Comment: I think that means you are referencing a namespace or something like that 4 real

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is in understanding how overload resolution for `detail::try_add_pointer<T>(0)` works. Substituting `T` into `detail::try_add_pointer` is meant to produce an overload set that will always contain at least one member (the variable argument overload).

Whether or not the overload taking an `int` is discarded during overload resolution ([SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)) is determined by the success of substituting `T` into `typename std::remove_reference<T>::type*`. When substitution succeeds, the overload exists, and is a better match in overload resolution for 0 (ellipsis are the worst possible match compared an any other conversion sequence). Either way, whichever overload is picked up in overload resolution, `decltype(detail::try_add_pointer<T>(0))` will resolve to something that has a nested `::type` member.

So let's go on a case by case analysis:

1. "If T is a reference type" - Let's mark it `T = T2&`. Then `std::remove_reference<T>::type` is `T2`. The types to which we may form a reference are also the types to which we may form a pointer. So `std::remove_reference<T>::type*` is well-formed (it's `T2*`), and the first overload exists. It's picked up in overload resolution. The nested `::type` of its return type is `T2*`.
2. "Otherwise, if T names an object type, a function type that is not cv- or ref-qualified, or a (possibly cv-qualified) void type" - In this case `std::remove_reference<T>::type` is simply `T`. We can form a pointer to any of the types in the previous list, and so `std::remove_reference<T>::type*` is well formed again (and it's `T*`). The first overload again exists and is picked up in overload resolution. The nested `::type` of its return type is `T*`.
3. "Otherwise (if T is a cv- or ref-qualified function type)" - The interesting bit. This speaks of types like `void (int) const&`. Here again `std::remove_reference<T>::type` is `T`. But we are not allowed to form a pointer to `T`, the base language prohibits it. Therefore `std::remove_reference<T>::type*` is ill-formed, and for this overload resolution the first overload is disregarded. Left with only the second overload, it's the one picked up by overload resolution. The nested `::type` of its return type is `T`.

Answer (score 1):

The inheritance is just a way of using the `type_identity` wrapper (already needed to form valid return types) to define the trait with minimal effort.  The overload trick relies on the fact that `std::remove_reference` is the identity for non-reference types and that (having dealt with references) `std::add_pointer<T>` is `T*` except when there is **no such type** at all.  In that case, SFINAE kills off the `int` overload and the `...` is selected (where just `T` is produced).