# std::add_pointer implementation for non-static member functions

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std

This question is a follow-up of [A question regarding the implementation of std::add_pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57506069/a-question-regarding-the-implementation-of-stdadd-pointer)

Under [std::add_pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_pointer)

there is the following reference:

> Otherwise (if T is a cv- or ref-qualified function type), provides the
>   member typedef type which is the type T.

Based on reading [Non-static member functions: const-, volatile-, and ref-qualified member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions), my understanding is that a for a non-static member function with given `cv`and/or `ref` qualification,

a) the `cv` qualification of the function applies to the `this` pointer as well, within the scope of the function

b) the `ref` qualification of the function does not apply to the `this` pointer within the scope of the function

Given this, why is it that `std::add_pointer` cannot provide the member `typedef` `type` `T*` in the case of a non-static member function with `cv` or `ref` qualification?

Comment: There's simply no function pointer to cv- or ref-qualified function type. Such type just doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [[dcl.ptr]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.ptr#4):

> [ *Note:* Forming a pointer to reference type is ill-formed; see
>   [dcl.ref]. **Forming a function pointer type is ill-formed if the
>   function type has *cv-qualifiers* or a *ref-qualifier*; see
>   [dcl.fct].** Since the address of a bit-field cannot be taken, a
>   pointer can never point to a bit-field.  — *end
>   note* ]

The pointer-to-cv-qualified-function type you are imagining is actually nonexistent.  Therefore, `std::add_pointer` cannot produce such a type :)

Answer (score 0):

A non-static member function type cannot be formed. Such a thing does not exist.

```
struct T {
   int func() const;
};
```

`func` does not have a type. You cannot ever use it as an expression on its own.

```
using mf = int (T::*)() const; 
mf myfunc = &T::func;
```

`mf` is a pointer to  member function type. It is not a function type; pointers to non-static members (including member functions) are data, not functions.

A cv or ref qualification on a member function does not qalify the function type, which does not exist, but the type of the implicit "this" parameter.

The paragraph you quote only applies to non-member or static member functions.